# Point Cloud Library: How visualize a set of 3D point stored in a C++ <vector>?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, point-cloud-library

I've searched here about this question, but seems no one have this question.

How can I draw with PCL visualizer a set of 3D points stored in a C++ ?

The vector it's filled of structs like this:

```
struct point {

 float x;
 float y;
 float z;
};
```

How can I draw this set of points using PCL in a window? At every elaboration of vector, the PCL window will be updated with new points of interest in the vector.

I'm on Visual C++ 2010, Win7 64bit...I've correctly installed PCL library and visual c++ enviromental variables/linker/etc to use PCL.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think this may be what your looking for : http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cloud_viewer.php#cloud-viewer

Comment: I have read it...but I don't understand how set every x,y,z instead of that defining of functions for every axis...

Comment: I think this could help: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/adding_custom_ptype.php#adding-custom-ptype

Comment: perfect...thanks...if you post this as answer, I can accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define `pcl::PointXYZ pt`, and `pt.x=point.x, pt.y=point.y, pt.z=point.z` 
then apply PointView to show your point clouds.
this is very essential part in PCL